# How to make a dashed line legend with d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I usually make a line legend by appending a `rect` giving it a very small height so that it looks like a line.

But now I need a dashed line legend. I am not able to do it by my old way. Can anyone show me a quick example of how to make a line legend with `append('path')` with d3.js?

[image: Dashed line legend example]

Comment: Take a look at the `stroke-dasharray` property for strokes that can easily be used to make dashed lines. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray

Comment: Following on from the above comment, use a svg `line` element rather than a thin rect, as the dashes going along the top and bottom edges won't match each other. Set stroke-width to make the line as thick as you want

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can make it like this with a `line` DOM:

```
  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(ageNames.slice().reverse())//data set for legends
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("line")//making a line for legend
      .attr("x1", width - 28)
      .attr("x2", width)
      .attr("y1", 10)
      .attr("y2", 10)
      .style("stroke-dasharray","5,5")//dashed array for line
      .style("stroke", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 44)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

Working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ow6EhX715srlb6naUdJW?p=preview)

Hope this work