# How to create a d3.js legend with both solid and dashed elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've recently started to learn d3.js and I've encountered some issues around creating a legend that has **both solid rectangles and dashed lines** to represent the bars and lines in the chart.

Heres an example of the data I am trying to plot:

[image: Bar graph with dashed line trend]

And here is an example of a legend I'd like to create:

[image: egend sample]

Here is the code I tried to use for my legend:

```
legend.append('rect')
  .attr('id', 'legend')
  .attr('x', this.state.width * 0.96)
  .attr('width', this.state.width * 0.025)
  .attr('height', this.state.width * 0.025)
  .attr('fill', z);
```

I've tried using this snippet from this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35516083/how-to-make-a-dashed-line-legend-with-d3-js) however it then makes all legend elements dashed.

```
.style("stroke-dasharray","5,5")
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could separate `legend` into two groups based on the data- one for the bars and another for dashed lines:

For the bar legend:

```
barLegend.append('rect')
  .attr('x', this.state.width * 0.96)
  .attr('width', this.state.width * 0.025)
  .attr('height', this.state.width * 0.025)
  .attr('fill', z);
```

For the line legend:

```
lineLegend.append('line')
      .attr('x1', this.state.width * 0.96 )
      .attr('x2', (this.state.width * 0.96) + 30)
      .attr('y1', 10)
      .attr('y2', 10)
      .style('stroke-dasharray','5,5')
      .style('stroke', z);
```

Comment: There is now a dashed line beside each filled-in rectangles on my legend

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Used part of @valangars answer but added filters on both sections to only allocate the legend element with their desired style.

```
.filter(function(d){
  return(d === 'dashed line data name');
  })
  .attr('x1', this.state.width * 0.96 )
  .attr('x2', (this.state.width * 0.96) + 30)
  .attr('y1', 10)
  .attr('y2', 10)
  .style('stroke-dasharray','5,5')
  .style('stroke', z);
```

Thanks!